# Intuition behind energy not being conserved in Rheonomous mechanical system

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, time, constrained-dynamics

firstly, this is what [Rheonomous System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheonomous) means. So, in such a system, the kinetic energy is not exactly just a quadratic function of generalized velocities because one of the generalized coordinates maybe explicitly defined as a function of time. This means Euler's theorem of homogeneous function can't be applied to kinetic energy this way:

$$
\sum_i \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{q} = 2T
$$
as $T$ is no longer a homogenous function of degree 2.

Now imagine if the lagrangian is just $L = T$. So, the total energy ($T$) is no longer equal to the hamiltonian $$H =\sum_i \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}} \dot{q_i} - L = \sum_i \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}} \dot{q_i} - T.$$ Here, $H$ is conserved whereas $E = T$ might not be.

My question is regarding why exactly is this the case? My guess would be that specifying the time dependence of one of the generalized coordinates transforms the lagrangian as having a time dependent potential $U$ or something which might violate time translation symmetry. It'd be great if someone could explain where the time translation symmetry would be violated?

If you want an example of such a system please let me know

Comment: If $L$ depends on coordinate that depends on time, why do you assume $H$ is conserved? Maybe specify a concrete example, this may help to clear up the question.

Comment: If $L$ has explicit time dependence, then (i) $L$ could still be quadratic in $\dot{q}$ and (ii) $H$ is not necessarily conserved.